# From where can I download classes12.jar file for jdk7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am new to WCD programming. So I am not understanding from where can I download classes12.jar file. I also don't know exactly whether it is automatically available with jdk or oracle or it has to be downloaded. And where should I place the file after downloading????

Comment: This was the first hit on google: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-10201-088211.html . You will need a (free) account at Oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That file would be the Oracle drivers. You need to look at the Oracle (database) web site to find the correct variety for your version of Java and your release number of Oracle.

If you have database admins you can check with, they might be able to supply the right jar file.

*Note*

The 12 refers to Java version 1.2. Up to a point, Oracle used this naming convention. Then they just sort of quit paying attention. It was pretty much justified as Java became more and more stable between versions.